# How do i call a javascript function from a text field without submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have create a HTML page with some JavaScript code. Here is the code

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function doIt(){
        window.location = document.getElementById('url').value;
    }
   </script>
   <input type="text" id="url" />
```

I want that when some one press the enter after type the URL. The page redirect to the given URL automatically. How i can do this? Please suggest me some code

Comment: are you familiar with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code:

```
<html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function doIt(){     
       window.location.href = document.getElementById('url').value;
    }   
    document.onkeypress=function(e){
        var e=window.event || e;        
        if(e.keyCode===13) doIt();       
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="url" value="http://www."/> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your attaching the `keypress` to the `document` `element`. That is not the ideal solution...

Comment: @Xander, your code is correct. but,mine is very simple to understand. anyway, you are open to say that you are correct, when no one said you are wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

If your not using jQuery, the following is a complete example:

```
function addEvent(obj, type, fn) {
    if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj['e' + type + fn] = fn;
        obj[type + fn] = function() {
            obj['e' + type + fn](window.event);
        }
        obj.attachEvent('on' + type, obj[type + fn]);
    } else obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
}

addEvent(window, 'load', function() {
    addEvent(document.getElementById('url'), 'keyup', function(e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

        if (code == 13)
            window.location.href = this.value;
    });
});
```

**Example** - http://jsfiddle.net/4PDt4/

*Credits for the **addEvent** code snippet:* - http://ejohn.org/projects/flexible-javascript-events/

Comment: How i can use this function in my code? can please post an example?

Comment: @Xander should i use jquery file?

Comment: @RizwanKhan jQuery will simplify - I've updated my answer to provide a complete example...

Answer (score 1):

see live demo at http://jsfiddle.net/qiao/RGqwD/2/

```
var input = document.getElementById('url');
input.onkeydown = function(e) {
  var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (key == 13) {
      window.location = input.value;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution: http://jsfiddle.net/YBLQx/1/

**JS**

```
(function () {

    var textField = document.getElementById('foo');

    function addHandler(el, event, handler) {
        if (el.addEventListener) {
            el.addEventListener (event, handler, false);
        } else if (el.attachEvent) {
            el.attachEvent (event, handler);
        }
    }

    addHandler(textField, 'keydown', textEntered);

    function textEntered(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            window.location = textField.value;
        }
    }
}());
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="foo" />
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="url" onblur="window.location.href='this.value'" />
```

the above is if the focus is taken out, like pressing tab

and then for enter, write onkeydown handler

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('url').onkeydown = function(e) {
      var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

     if (keyCode === 13) {
       window.location.href = this.value;
     }
 }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach a keypress event handler to the text box.  In your event handler, you would check if the key pressed was enter.  If so, do the redirect.  Look up event handlers.